# Add data to XML element within bash script

Tags: xml, bash, jboss, scripting

I have the following XML :

```
<remote host="${jboss.domain.master.address:127.0.0.1}"     port="${jboss.domain.master.port:9999}"  security-realm="ManagementRealm" />
```

I want to add a username=admin line into this block. Whats the best way of going about this. I have tried every sed combination and have been getting nowehere...

Comment: Can you show us some of the `sed` attempts you made?

Comment: Use a language with a real XML parser, rather than treating XML as plain text.

Comment: I understand one can use xmlstarlet, not really what im looking for here for a number of reasons outside of my control. I want to be able to accomplish this using sed/awk etc.

Comment: @EricRenouf none of them worked, so dont think they will be of much help

Answer (score 0):

Recommend against it, but:

```
xml=$( sed 's# /># username="admin"&#' <<< "$xml" )
```

Comment: kind of works.. but I need it added to a specific line in the config

Comment: would have been a good idea to mention that in your question, don't you think? Please spell out your requirements clearly in your question, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use text processing tools to edit XML. Use an XML-aware tool. For example, in [xsh](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-XSH2/xsh), you can just

```
open file.xml ;
$host = {'${jboss.domain.master.address:127.0.0.1}'} ; # ${ is special in xsh.
$port = {'${jboss.domain.master.port:9999}'} ;
$realm = 'ManagementRealm' ;

$n = //remote[@host=$host][@port=$port][@security-realm=$realm] ;
if (count($n) != 1) throw 'Found 0 or too many nodes.' ;
set $n/@username 'admin' ;
save :b ;
```